# Why to build a SSAS Cube?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, cube, olap-cube

I was just searching for the best explanations and reasons to build a OLAP Cube from Relational Data. Is that all about performance and query optimization?

It will be great if you can give links or point out best explanations and reasons for building a cube, as we can do all the things from relational database that we can do from cube and cube is faster to show results.Is there any other explanation or reasons?

Answer (score 13):

There are many reasons why you should use a cube for analytical proccessing.

1. Speed. Olap wharehouses are read only infrastractures providing 10 times faster queries than their oltp counterparts. See [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing)
2. Multiple data integration. On a cube you can easily use multiple data sources and do minimal work with many automated tasks (especially when you use SSIS) to intergrate them on a single analysis system. See [elt process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load)
3. Minimum code. That is, you need not write queries. Even though you can write MDX - the language of the cubes in SSAS, the BI Studio does most of the hard work for you. On a project I am working on, at first we used SSRS to provide reports for the client. The queries were long and hard to make and took days to implement. Their SSAS equivalent reports took us half an hour to make, writing only a few simple queries to trasform some data.
4. A cube provides reports and drill up-down-through, without the need to write additional queries. The end user can traverse the dimension automatically, as the aggregations are already stored in the warehouse. This helps as the users of the cube need only traverse its dimensions to produce their own reports without the need to write queries.
5. Is is part of the Bussiness Intelligence. When you make a cube it can be fed to many new technologies and help in the implementation of BI solutions.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a **top level** view, use OLAP. Say you have millions of rows detailing product sales and you want to know your monthly sales totals.

If you want **bottom-level** detail, use OLTP (e.g. SQL). Say you have millions of rows detailing product sales and want to examine one store's sales on one particular day to find potential fraud.

OLAP is good for big numbers. You wouldn't use it to examine string values, really...

Comment: Thanks Magnus for the message but  i couldn't find any requirement for Cube in small sets of Data ..for large sets of Data Cube is a good thing

Answer (score 1):

It's bit like asking why using JAVA/C++ when we can do everything with Assembly Language ;-) Building a cube (apart from performance) is giving you the [MDX language](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx_tutorial/gentle_introduction.html); this language has higher level concepts than SQL and is better with analytic tasks. Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551541/what-makes-access-to-olap-cubes-datamarts-and-similar-datastructures-faster-t) gives more info.

My 2 centavos.