# SSAS use to replace traditional way of querying database

Tags: ssas

I want to know can i use SSAS to replace traditional way of writing multiple complex stored procedures and getting o/p

for an example i have around 200 procedures having various requirements of business  which i use in 200 SSIS packages(one procedure per package) to generate 200 flat files , can SSAS help me to reduce the no. of procedures and packages and still get the required 200 flat files

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you are trying to achieve. 
If you use OLAP you will need to rebuild the DataWarehouse each time (SSIS supports this though) and then you will need

SSAS is data warehousing. There are no constraints, and the MDX language is not what you would call well documented so there would be a learning curve to implements the queries

Read [Why to build a SSAS Cube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528485/why-to-build-a-ssas-cube/12671341#12671341) for info on SSAS.

All in all you CAN use SSAS as a data source in SSIS. ([look here](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/DustinRyan/ssis/1456/connecting-to-and-querying-an-ssas-cube-in-ssis)) so it is a viable solution to query the Warehouse for your data. It is just not something I would do.